# when to use segment tree and when to use BIT

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I don't have a scenario. But for the generic case where we have to just

1. Update in a range (example clear all values in some range i-j)
2. Query for some value in a range. (example RMQ)
3. Make an update on an individual element ( a specific case of point 1)
4. Search for a particular value in a range ( again a specific case of point 2)

All these operations can be performed with either a BIT or a segment tree.But except **3** and some specific cases of **2** segment tree is much more efficient. (Infact BIT doesn't helps in any way for queries like RMQ)

The most clear advantage of BIT is its far easier to code.

Comment: What about updating in a range?or doing RMQ using BIT? Can u give me some pointers on that

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong. BIT is not good for updating a range or RMQ. Only Segment Tree can do this efficiently.

Comment: I don't know how to perform operation 2 & 4 with BIT, could you please give me a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Here are my thoughts after spending time with segment tree and BIT problems since few weeks, so i am quite new it)

BIT is easier to code, but there are situations which you can easily visualize and relate to a segment tree. Another advantage that BIT offers is that it takes the lesser space (O(n) space).

From what i feel, segment trees are easier to understand compared to BIT, so you can easily apply and relate it to a given situation. Lazy propagation is also simpler and easy to understand in segment trees. Thus, Segment tree lets you efficiently update over a range.